# CDF of Y given X is a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I'm new to probability and I have a question that I'm hoping you can help me solve. It should be really simple but I don't know where to start.
I'm given $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y=e^X$ and I'm told to determine the CDF of Y.

I don't really know where to start but I want to learn this so any help will be appreciated. I just need something to work with.
I know that $F(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty(f(x)) $ but I don't have the PDF so I'm not sure what to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $F(X)$ (or more correctly, $F_X(x)$) is _not_ given by the integral you write (which has value $1$ in all cases). -1 for a very badly proof-read question. What, for example, is meant by $X \sim (\mu,\sigma^2)$??

Comment: @DilipSarwate Hi, as I tried to say in my original post, I'm completely new to this. I honestly just want to learn it. I must have written something wrong in my notes, but this is what I knew and I'm just trying to show what my standpoint is. And sorry, I forgot the "N", I'm also new to writing like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These all go about the same way : $$ F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y) = P(e^X \le y) = P(X\le \log (y)) = F_X(\log (y))$$ where $F_X$ is the CDF of $X.$ (Although sometimes there's shenanigans with minus signs in the inequality. Or if the function isn't one-to-one.)

Here since $X$ is $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (I assume that's what you meant) we can take it a step further: $$P(X\le \log (y))  = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\le \frac{\log(y)-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \Phi\left(\frac{\log(y)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$ where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal, since we know that $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ is $N(0,1).$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I'm happy that you understood what I was trying to say. This helps a lot! But I'm still a bit unsure about the notation, is it correct to write $F_Y(y)=\Phi\left(\frac{log(y)-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$ as an answer?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. If you have a more specific question about the notation, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Two questions after this one I'm told to use the CDF to show that the PDF is $f(y)=1/(y*\sqrt(2*pi*\sigma^2)*exp(-((log(y)-\mu)^2)/2\sigma^2)$ 
What I'm told here is to differentiate the CDF, is that correct?

Comment: Well I said *about the notation*, but it's all good :). Yes, the PDF is the derivative of the CDF (when the CDF is differentiable). What you wrote down is similar what I get when I differentiate the CDF (it's a bit hard to read exactly what things are.. it might be identical). Remember you can use the fact that $F'_X(x)$ is the PDF of $X.$

Comment: Oh haha, sorry about that I didn't want to bother you but thank you so much for your time and your ekspertise, it's greatly appreciated!